# What is the array type for html elements in typescript?

Tags: types, typescript

I have a typescript variable that stores the result of a DOM query:

```
let games = document.getElementsByTagname("game");
```

But what is the correct type of the result array? I would expect an array that contains htmlelements?

```
// not working
let games : Array<HTMLElement> = document.getElementsByTagName("game");
// also not working
let games : NodeList<HTMLElement> = document.getElementsByTagName("game");
```

Comment: you can use Array<Element>/ Array<angular.IJQueryElement> as type, see anyone works or not?

Comment: I get this error when using Array<Element>:  'NodeListOf<Element>' is not assignable to type 'Element[]'. Property 'push' is missing in type 'NodeListOf<Element>'.

Comment: use NodeListOf<Element> instead of Array<Element>. It will probably solve your error.

Comment: If you want to use the element for any actions later, you need to cast in into an `NodeListOf<HTMLElement>`, else it wont let you take innerText, click etcetc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `NodeListOf<T>`, for example:

```
let games : NodeListOf<Element> = document.getElementsByTagName("game");
```

You could use type assertions to force it into an `HTMLElement[]`, but this would give misleading type information and make your tools lie.

Comment: Ah.. I didn't realise "NodeListOf" was actually a type... (what does the "Of" mean?). Also, why so many different types for DOM elements? (NodeList, NodeListOf, Element and HTMLElement). It seems a lot of hassle to keep casting from one type to another just to fetch a div from my DOM.

Comment: the "Of" means what that it is a NodeList OF the type X, for example `NodeListOf<HTMLElement>` means a list of the node type HTMLElement. The reason you need to cast is that there are hundreds of node types that can be yielded by javascripts querySelectors or other selectors, and in typescript you want to be certain to throw an error if wrong node type is yielded..